# Azure local emulator does not serve django static files correctly

Tags: django, iis, azure, visual-studio-2012

I have followed the Django / Visual Studio / Azure tutorial http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/python/tutorials/django-with-visual-studio/. I have a very simple application, basically one simple html template with one javascript and one css file (code examples at the end).

When I run the code in the local debugger, everything works fine. When I try to run the code in the local Azure emulator with default VS and Azure SDK provided settings, I get the html file as response for both the javascript and css requests. For example, request for `/static/calculator.js` returns the application's html template instead of `calculator.js`.

What could cause this behavior and how could this be fixed?

UPDATE:
It seems that as I run the website in Azure emulator, any url on the emulator host `127.0.0.2` will return the "main page", that is, the only view defined in `views.py`. For example, `127.0.0.2/` returns the webpage (as it should), and so does `127.0.0.2/nonexistenturl`. My hunch is that this is somehow due to misconfiguration of either fastcgi or IIS express as used by Azure emulator. What would be good starting points for trying to fix this problem?

Code examples:

Html template links:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/static/calculator.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/static/calculator.js"></script>
```

`urls.py`:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
                   url(r'^$', 'ExamCalculator.Calculator.views.main_page'),
)
```

in `settings.py` staticfiles related settings should be correct:

```
STATIC_ROOT = 'C:/.../static/'
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
# Additional locations of static files
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    # Put strings here, like "/home/html/static" or "C:/www/django/static".
    # Always use forward slashes, even on Windows.
    # Don't forget to use absolute paths, not relative paths.
)
STATICFILES_FINDERS = (
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder',
#    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.DefaultStorageFinder',
)
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    ...
)
```

Comment: Does the azure emulator run the django development server via `manage.py runserver` or does it use it's own server?

Comment: I am a total newbie on Visual studio and azure, but my impression is that the azure emulator uses IIS and fastcgi, as in azure cloud. The "debugger" runs with manage.py runserver and works correctly.

Comment: In that case, you need to look at how to set up IIS to serve static files. Django's development server can serve them, but isn't designed to. You can force django to serve them by adding the urls, but it is not recommended for production use. [development](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/static-files/#serving-static-files-in-development) and [production](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/static-files/#serving-static-files-in-production) info

Comment: I agree. Problem is mostly on how to do this in the context of visual studio and azure emulator - the deployment is so automated that it is difficult to know where to start debugging deployment problems. I know how to do this for nginx on Linux, but it does not help here...

Comment: Oh I see, my mistake. Unfortunately I know nothing about azure or visual studio relating to django. I thought you were asking about django specifically. Good luck, hopefully someone else has an answer for you.